# Validation failed in Entity Framework, ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

My application using ASP.NET MVC3 with EF4.1, deployed on IIS7. Recently I've meet an error when trying to save an entity to an existing database on the production server, but everything goes well on my development machine.

I tried to build deploy package in VS2010 and import that package in IIS7, also, I've tried to upload all the solutions and create an application in IIS7 manually, but both of the 2 sites come to an error when executing a function that saves an entity to the database.

Error message is pasted below, but the physical path in error message does not exist in the production server, it's a path in my local development machine. This makes me confused. Has anybody ever seen this before?

BTW, I've fully backed up my database and restored it on the production server, so all the databases are same.

I'm open to hear any advice.

Thanks

Cheng

Error message:

> Server Error in '/xxxx' Application. Validation failed for one or
>   more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation
>   failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property
>   for more details.
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding
>   the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the
>   exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.]
>
> System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +212
>   xxxxx.Models.SetupRepository.CreateApplicationOption(Guid companyId) in 
>   D:\xxxx\Models\SetupRepository.cs:59
>   xxxxx.MvcApplication.MvcApplication_PostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e) > in D:\xxxx\Global.asax.cs:87
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Comment: "*See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.*": Did you follow this advice? In those details will likely be the key for a solution. If you are on a production machine and can't debug I would recommend you to catch the `DbEntityValidationException` (coming from `SaveChanges`, I guess), pull out `EntityValidationErrors` (and write or send it to somewhere) and then rethrow the exception.

Comment: Thank you, that's right, something wrong in the entity.